# Wordpress Woocommerce get products by brand, not showing all results

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

For last two days i tried to understand why i cannot get all products that are in a specific brand that are published.
Here is the code i use:

```
$args = array(
      'post_type'           => 'product',
      'post_status'         => 'publish',
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
      'posts_per_page'      => -1,
      'meta_query'          => array(
        array(
          'key'             => '_visibility',
          'value'       => array('catalog', 'visible'),
          'compare'         => 'IN'
        )
      ),
      'tax_query'           => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_brand',
            'terms'         => $brandId,
            'field'         => 'id',
            'operator'      => 'IN'
          )
      )
    );
#get all products based on args for that brand
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This should get all the products for a specific brand ( by ID ) but instead of getting all products it returns only 20 or 22 products from a total of 50 or 100.

If i add these conditions i get other results, ordered.

```
'orderby'             => 'id',
'order'               => 'ASC',
```

It is weird for me, can you give me an Hint?..i use  **'posts_per_page'=> -1,** to get all results.
What i', missing? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: You are ignoring sticky posts, how many sticky posts do you have?

Comment: Even that value is 0 or filter removed , i get the same results.How that will affect my query? Thanks.

Comment: Any other ideea guys? :(

Comment: What's the `$brandId` value like?

Comment: The brand id value is 125,100 (many values)...it doesn't matter. What i'm trying to do is to get all products from all brands, check if at least 1 product is in stock for that brand, if yes do something, But i cannot decide properly becouse if i have 100 products and i get only 22 in my query. Make sense?